# How to set navigation bar to solid color

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

When I change the background color of the navigation bar, it is opaque like the following.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .black
```

[image]

Then if I set translucent to false, I don't see any color like the following

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .black    
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
```

[image]

Any idea on how to make a solid background color?

Answer (score 3):

Set it's `barTintColor`

Example:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .red
```

Comment: @YunCHan My bad. that's `barTintColor` not `tintColor`. Updated answer

Comment: Oh, BARtintColor! Thanks it worked.

Comment: @YunCHan Yeahh... just `tintColor` will affect the color of the `navigationItem`s such as the bar button's font color.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `barTintColor` instead of the `backgroundColor`:

> The tint color to apply to the navigation bar ***background***.
>
> <sub>https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624931-bartintcolor</sub>

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .black
```